# Why do flash messages in Laravel Livewire only show once?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a problem with flash messages not showing when using Laravel Livewire.

If I use just wire:model and then click the save button everything works fine and the success message is displayed. But if I use wire:model.defer the flash message only works once after the page has been refreshed, so for example, the page loads, I change a form field and click save everything works fine. But, let's say I forgot to change a field and now click save, the flash message doesn't show, only if I reload the page.

This person appears to have the same issue but no solutions offered. [same problem?](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/discussions/2921)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use Livewire\Component;

class ProfileSettings extends Component
{
    public $display_name;
    public $bio;
    public $location;
    public $website_url;
    public $subscription;
    public $hide_status;
    public $hide_profile;


    public function UpdateProfile()
    {
        $validatedData = $this->validate(
            [
                'display_name' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:40', 'regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9.\s]+$/'],
                'bio' => ['nullable', 'string', 'max:1000'],
                'location' => ['nullable', 'string', 'max:100'],
                'website_url' => ['nullable', 'max:100', 'url'],
                'subscription' => ['nullable', 'numeric', 'min:4.99', 'max:29.99'],
                'hide_status' => 'boolean',
                'hide_profile' => 'boolean', 
            ]
        );

        // Store subscription price in cents.
        if($validatedData['subscription'])
            $validatedData['subscription'] = $this->subscription * 100;
        else
            $validatedData['subscription'] = NULL; 
  
        User::where('id', auth::user()->id)->update($validatedData);

        session()->flash('message', 'Profile settings successfully updated!');
    }
    

    // Populate the form fields with stored data.
    public function mount() {
        $this->display_name = Auth::user()->display_name;
        $this->bio = Auth::user()->bio;
        $this->location = Auth::user()->location;
        $this->website_url = Auth::user()->website_url;
        
        // If a subscription price is set, convert from cents to dollars
        // with two decimal places for displaying.
        if (Auth::user()->subscription)
        {
            $dollars = Auth::user()->subscription / 100;
            $this->subscription = number_format($dollars, 2, '.', ',');
        }

        $this->hide_status = Auth::user()->hide_status;
        $this->hide_profile = Auth::user()->hide_profile;
    }


    public function render()
    {   
        
        return view('livewire.profile-settings');
    }
}
```

```
    <div>
        <h3 class="text-xl mb-2">Profile</h3>
        <p>Here you can edit your profile information, privacy and subscription details.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-white rounded-md lg:shadow-md shadow col-span-2">
        <form wire:submit.prevent="UpdateProfile">
            <div class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-3 lg:p-6 p-4">

                <div>
                    <label for="display_name">Display Name</label>
                    <input id="display_name" type="text" class="shadow-none with-border focus:ring-0" wire:model.defer="display_name">
                    @error('display_name')<x-validation-errors :message="$message"/>@enderror
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="bio">Bio</label>  
                    <textarea id="bio" rows="3" class="shadow-none bg-gray-100 with-border focus:ring-0" wire:model.defer="bio"></textarea>
                    @error('bio')<x-validation-errors :message="$message"/>@enderror
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="location">Location</label>
                    <input id="location" type="text" class="shadow-none with-border focus:ring-0" wire:model.defer="location">
                    @error('location')<x-validation-errors :message="$message"/>@enderror
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="website_url">Website URL</label>
                    <input id="website_url" type="text" class="shadow-none with-border focus:ring-0" wire:model.defer="website_url">
                    @error('website_url')<x-validation-errors :message="$message"/>@enderror
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="subscription">Subscription Price - minimum $4.99 USD per month or leave blank for free.</label>
                    <div class="flex items-center">
                        <div class="-mr-1 bg-gray-100 border px-3 py-3 rounded-l-md">$</div>
                        <input id="subscription" type="text" class="shadow-none with-border focus:ring-0" wire:model.defer="subscription">
                    </div>
                        @error('subscription')<x-validation-errors :message="$message"/>@enderror
                </div>
                <div class="mt-5 space-y-5 ">
                    <div class="flex justify-between items-center">
                        <div>
                            <h4>Activity Status</h4>
                            <div>Enable to hide your last seen status on your profile.</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="switches-list -mt-8 is-large">
                            <div class="switch-container">
                                <input type="hidden" value="0" wire:mode.defer="hide_status">
                                <label class="switch"><input type="checkbox" value="1" wire:model.defer="hide_status"><span class="switch-button"></span></label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="flex justify-between items-center">
                        <div>
                            <h4>Hide Profile</h4>
                            <div>Enable to hide your profile from search results.</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="switches-list -mt-8 is-large">
                            <div class="switch-container">
                                <input type="hidden" value="0"wire:mode.defer="hide_profile" >
                                <label class="switch"><input type="checkbox" value="1" wire:model.defer="hide_profile"><span class="switch-button"></span></label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
               
                <div>
                <x-auth-session-status class="mb-4" :status="session('message')"/>
                </div>

                <div class="flex items-center justify-center">
                    <x-button>
                        <span wire:loading.delay wire:target="UpdateProfile"><x-loading /></span>
                        <span wire:loading.remove wire:target="UpdateProfile">{{ __('Save') }}</span>
                    </x-button>
                </div>
    
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

```
@if ($status)
<div x-data="{ show: true }" x-show="show"
    class="flex justify-between items-center bg-green-200 relative py-3 px-3 rounded-lg">
    <div>
        <div class="ml-2 text-sm text-green-600">
        {{ $status }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="button" @click="show = false" class=" text-green-700">
            <span class="text-2xl">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this has less to do with `Livewire` and more to do with `Alpine` and it's lifecycle. The reason it works the first time is because the `Alpine` component is not in the `DOM` and so when the flash message is added to the `DOM`, it is initialized with `x-data="{ show: true }` so your component is displayed. When you click the `close` button to change the value of `show` to `false`, then update something and press `save`, the component is already in the `DOM` and so not initialized again meaning the value of `show` is not set to `true`.

There are examples of using flash messages with `Livewire` and `Alpine` in the `Livewaire` stack of `Jetstream`. It uses events rather than `session()`.

```php
public function save()
{
    // ...
    $this->emit('saved');
}
```

```html
<div x-data="{ shown: false, timeout: null }"
    x-init="@this.on('saved', () => { clearTimeout(timeout); shown = true; timeout = setTimeout(() => { shown = false }, 2000); })"
    x-show.transition.opacity.out.duration.1500ms="shown"
    style="display: none;">
    {{ __('Updated.') }}
</div>
```

This initializes the `Alpine` component and attaches a listener for the `saved` event so that any time it hears the `saved` event it triggers a function to execute which shows the message and then clears.

You could remove the `setTimeout` stuff and just have it set `shown = true` if you wanted to allow users to manually clear the message.

Comment: Excellent! That works much better, I didn't think to have a look at jetstream and how they did it. Thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form wire:submit.prevent="update">
<div>
    @if (session()->has('message'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            {{ session('message') }}
        </div>
    @endif
</div>

Title: <input wire:model="post.title" type="text">

<button>Save</button>
```

in your blade insert div